# Fitting two sets of values by changing x-axis

Tags: curve-fitting, growth-model

I have two datasets. The first one consist of measurements with a known date. The second dataset consists of measurements along a distance axis. The second dataset is sequentially deposited (for example an ice-core) with an unknown growth rate. Values in the two datasets are expected to match within a certain random error. An example:

```
curve <- data.frame(date = as.Date(c('01/09/11', '01/10/11', '01/11/11', '01/12/11', '01/01/12', '01/02/12', '01/03/12', '01/04/12', '01/05/12', '01/06/12', '01/07/12', '01/08/12', '01/09/12'), format = "%d/%m/%y"), value = c(3.33, 3.80, 4.19, 4.43, 4.56, 4.76, 4.71, 4.96, 4.72, 4.66, 4.35, 4.12, 3.88))

points <- data.frame(distance = 1:10, value = c(3.5, 4.2, 4.5, 4.4, 4.7, 4.8, 5.1, 4.9, 4.1, 3.7))

library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

a <- ggplot(curve, aes(x = date, y = value)) + geom_line() + scale_x_date(name = "Month", breaks = date_breaks("months"), labels = date_format("%b"))
b <- ggplot(points, aes(x = distance, y = value)) + geom_point()

grid.arrange(a,b,ncol=1)
```

[image]

I call the dataset with known date "curve" because the number of measurements is much larger than for the dataset with a distance axis ("point" dataset). In reality both of them consist of measurement points, but I suppose I could approximate the curve dataset to an actual curve by using loess or splines. I would like to fit the "point" dataset to the "curve" dataset by changing the x-axis (or growth rate) for the "point" dataset with a constraint that the growth rate > 0 (distance between "point"s). I assume that I would be making a growth model for the distance axis.

What would be the best method to do this kind of fitting? Is there an R package developed for this kind of problem?

Comment: It sounds a bit like you're asking for something akin to [dynamic time warping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_time_warping). That garners a few hits here as a [search term](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=dynamic+time+warping), though there are a number of other ways to try to estimate some continuous nonlinear relationship between your two variables.

Comment: I would have guessed that you could fairly easily use `nls` or one of the other optimizers in R to solve for the offset to the points that would minimize the (value-value)-differences between the curve and the point-set. It would require that we know that the intervals are on the same scale.

Comment: Dynamic time wrapping sounds promising. Thanks for pointing that out. I will look into it. There are papers on this topic, for instance: http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs11004-011-9352-7. They use an approach which is probably connected to @Dwin´s suggestion. I am not a mathematician, so understanding what they did takes time...

Answer (score 1):

@Glen_b suggested using dynamic time warping. There is an [R package](http://dtw.r-forge.r-project.org) for DTW calculations. It works for the example, except for that I have not managed to implement the constraint that "growth rate" or rather minimum step in this context should be > 0. On the other hand implementing such a constraint for the example data would not make much sense because of few reference index points. So here is how it goes:

```
library(dtw)
res <- dtw(points$value, curve$value, keep = T, step=typeIIIc)

library(plyr)
names <- data.frame(date = curve$date, 
              index = seq_along(curve$date))

points$date <- as.Date(mapvalues(res$index2, from = names$index, 
        to = as.character(names$date)))

library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

ggplot() + geom_line(data = curve, aes(x = date, y = value)) + 
 geom_text(data = points, aes(x=date, y=value, label = distance), 
 color = "red") + scale_x_date(name = "Month", 
 breaks = date_breaks("months"), labels = date_format("%b"))
```

[image]

Red numbers are the fitted points. Line represents the "curve". Let´s try this on more reference index points:

```
new.date <- seq.Date(from = curve$date[1], 
      to = curve$date[length(curve$date)], by = "day")

curve <- merge(curve, data.frame(date = new.date, 
     index = seq_along(new.date)), by = "date", all = F, sort = F)
lo.c <- loess(value ~ index, curve, span = 0.4)

new.curve <- data.frame(date = new.date, 
       index = seq_along(new.date), 
       value = predict(lo.c, seq_along(new.date)))

## New.curve
ggplot() + geom_line(data = new.curve, aes(x = date, y = value)) + 
    geom_point(data = curve, aes(x = date, y = value), 
    color = "red") + scale_x_date(name = "Month", 
    breaks = date_breaks("months"), labels = date_format("%b"))
```

[image]

Red points are the old reference index points. Line represents loess curve fitted on the "curve" values.

I encounter problems when trying to define the `step` for `dtw`:

```
res.new <- dtw(points$value, new.curve$value, keep = T, 
       step=typeIIIc)

#Error in dtw(points$value, new.curve$value, keep = T, 
  step = typeIIIc) : 
      No warping paths exists that is allowed by constraints
```

If I remove the `step`, fitting works, but now the function fits query indices on reference indices n = length(new.date).

```
res.new <- dtw(points$value, new.curve$value, keep = T)
plot(res.new, "twoway")
```

[image]

I want only one time point for each query. Not an average over a longer period, so I am having difficulties to make this method work for the problem. This is no doubt my fault, because [`dtw` package documentation](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dtw/dtw.pdf) is not very easy to understand. Any suggestions how to proceed?

Comment: More about the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20397402/how-to-fit-known-values-to-a-known-curve-by-changing-x-axis